# Result after pivot is scrambled

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this result in my query without pivoting and it looks like this

```
Branch  Payroll  Items
AAA        0    BasicPay
AAA        0    Overtime
AAA        0    Paid Hol
AAA        0    Sunday OT
AAA        0    Thirteen MO
AAA        0    Gross Amount
AAA        0    WithTax
AAA        0    SSS Cont
AAA        0    SSS Loan
AAA        0    Pagibig Cont
AAA        0    Pagibig Loan
AAA        0    Medicare
AAA        0    Total Ded
AAA        0    Net with OD
AAA        0    Net no OD
AAA        0    CASH ADVANCE
AAA        0    MEAL
AAA        0    Cola
AAA        0    Incentives
```

but after pivoting the table my result in items scrambled.. and here is the result..

```
Items          AAA
BasicPay        0
CASH ADVANCE    0
Cola            0
Gross Amount    0
Incentives      0
MEAL            0
Medicare        0
Net no OD       0
Net with OD     0
Overtime        0
Pagibig Cont    0
Pagibig Loan    0
Paid Hol        0
SSS Cont        0
SSS Loan        0
Sunday OT       0
Thirteen MO     0
Total Ded       0
WithTax         0
```

why is this happening?? I want to retain the order of my items field after pivoting..how can i do this? please help thanks a lot..
here is my query

```
select * from( 
 Select unpivots.Branch,items,items2  from(
 Select   BranchId as testid,Coalesce([BasicPay],0)[BasicPay],Coalesce(Overtime,0)overtime,coalesce([Paid Hol],0)[Paid Hol],coalesce([Sunday OT],0)[Sunday OT],Coalesce([Thirteen MO],0)[Thirteen MO],
     coalesce([Gross Amount],0)[Gross Amount],coalesce([WithTax],0)[WithTax],coalesce([SSS Cont],0)[SSS Cont],coalesce([SSS Loan],0)[SSS Loan],coalesce([Pagibig Cont],0)[Pagibig Cont],coalesce([Pagibig Loan],0)[Pagibig Loan]
     ,coalesce(Medicare,0)[Medicare],Coalesce([Total Ded],0)[Total Ded],coalesce([Net with OD],0)[Net with OD],Coalesce([Net no OD],0)[Net no OD],coalesce([CASH ADVANCE],0)[CASH ADVANCE],coalesce([MEAL],0)[MEAL],Coalesce([Cola],0)[Cola],coalesce([Incentives],0)[Incentives],Branch from(
   Select  BranchId as testid,Coalesce([BasicPay],0)[BasicPay],Coalesce(Overtime,0)overtime,coalesce([Paid Hol],0)[Paid Hol],coalesce([Sunday OT],0)[Sunday OT],Coalesce([Thirteen MO],0)[Thirteen MO],
     coalesce([Gross Amount],0)[Gross Amount],coalesce([WithTax],0)[WithTax],coalesce([SSS Cont],0)[SSS Cont],coalesce([SSS Loan],0)[SSS Loan],coalesce([Pagibig Cont],0)[Pagibig Cont],coalesce([Pagibig Loan],0)[Pagibig Loan]
     ,coalesce(Medicare,0)[Medicare],Coalesce([Total Ded],0)[Total Ded],coalesce([Net with OD],0)[Net with OD],Coalesce([Net no OD],0)[Net no OD],coalesce([CASH ADVANCE],0)[CASH ADVANCE],coalesce([MEAL],0)[MEAL],Coalesce([Cola],0)[Cola],coalesce([Incentives],0)[Incentives]
    from
     (
      Select distinct 
        --pr_employees.Fullname as Name
       --,
       PR_Employees.BranchID,PR_payroll.BasicPay as [BasicPay]
       ,PR_Empearnings.EarningAmt
       ,PR_Earnings.Description
       ,pr_payroll.Overtime
       ,pr_payroll.Period
       ,Pr_payroll.SundayOT as [Sunday OT]
       ,Pr_Payroll.PaidHol as [Paid Hol]
       ,pr_payroll.ThirteenthMonthPay as [Thirteen MO]
       ,pr_payroll.Grosspay as [Gross Amount]
       ,pr_payroll.WithHoldingTax as [WithTax]
       ,pr_payroll.SSSPremium as [SSS Cont]
       ,pr_payroll.SSSLoan as [SSS Loan]
       ,pr_payroll.PagibigPremium as [Pagibig Cont]
       ,pr_payroll.PagibigLoan as [Pagibig Loan]
       ,pr_payroll.NHIPPremium as Medicare
       ,pr_payroll.TotalDeductions as [Total Ded]
       ,pr_Payroll.netpay as [Net with OD]
       ,pr_payroll.netnoOd as [Net no OD]
       ,prchargesAdvances.Credit
       ,prchargesadvancesTypes.ChargesTypeName
     from pr_employees
      left join pr_payroll on PR_Employees.EmpID=PR_Payroll.EmpID
      left join PR_EmpEarnings on PR_Payroll.EmpID=PR_EmpEarnings.EmpID
      left join PR_Earnings on PR_EmpEarnings.EarningId=pr_earnings.earningid
      left join PR_Overtime on PR_Overtime.EmpID=PR_Payroll.EmpID
      left join PRChargesAdvances on PRChargesAdvances.transactiondate=pr_payroll.period   
       and prchargesadvances.empid=pr_payroll.empid
      left join PRChargesAdvancesTypes on PRChargesAdvances.ChargeTypeID=PRChargesAdvancesTypes.ChargesTypeID
     where PR_Payroll.Period='8/31/2013' 
  ) as Source
  pivot 
  (
     MAX([EarningAmt])
     FOR [Description] IN ([COLa],[Incentives]) 
  ) as pvt
   pivot 
  (
     MAX([Credit])
     FOR [ChargesTypeName] IN ([MEAL],[CASH ADVANCE]) 
  ) as pvt2)AS Srck
  right join PR_Branch on Srck.testID=PR_Branch.BranchID)as src
  unpivot(items for items2 in ([BasicPay],Overtime,[Paid Hol],[Sunday OT],[Thirteen MO],
     [Gross Amount],[WithTax],[SSS Cont],[SSS Loan],[Pagibig Cont],[Pagibig Loan]
     ,Medicare,[Total Ded],[Net with OD],[Net no OD],[CASH ADVANCE],[MEAL],[Cola],[Incentives]))as unpivots

    )as latestsrc
    pivot (sum(items) for items2 in ([BasicPay],Overtime,[Paid Hol],[Sunday OT],[Thirteen MO],
     [Gross Amount],[WithTax],[SSS Cont],[SSS Loan],[Pagibig Cont],[Pagibig Loan]
     ,Medicare,[Total Ded],[Net with OD],[Net no OD],[CASH ADVANCE],[MEAL],[Cola],[Incentives])) as pvt


     unpivot(Payroll for Items in ([BasicPay],Overtime,[Paid Hol],[Sunday OT],[Thirteen MO],
     [Gross Amount],[WithTax],[SSS Cont],[SSS Loan],[Pagibig Cont],[Pagibig Loan]
     ,Medicare,[Total Ded],[Net with OD],[Net no OD],[CASH ADVANCE],[MEAL],[Cola],[Incentives]))as unpvt
     pivot (max(payroll) for Branch in ([aaa]))as pvt
```

Comment: please share sql statement you use...

Comment: There is a lot going on in your query that your example output doesn't show. Perhaps you should give some simpler examples with a sqlfiddle linked. May I also suggest that you refactor your code to use CASE WHEN and Group By instead of pivot and unpivot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `row_number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0))` as column and order by this column, hope you will solved your problem, example related to your data is given below.

```
CREATE table #Temp (Branch varchar(255),Payroll int, Itemsvarchar(255))    
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES
('AAA',0,'BasicPay')
,('AAA',0,'Overtime')
,('AAA',0,'Paid Hol')
,('AAA',0,'Sunday OT')
,('AAA',0,'Thirteen MO')
,('AAA',0,'Gross Amount')
,('AAA',0,'WithTax')
,('AAA',0,'SSS Cont')
,('AAA',0,'SSS Loan')
,('AAA',0,'Pagibig Cont')
,('AAA',0,'Pagibig Loan')
,('AAA',0,'Medicare')
,('AAA',0,'Total Ded')
,('AAA',0,'Net with OD')
,('AAA',0,'Net no OD')
,('AAA',0,'CASH ADVANCE')
,('AAA',0,'MEAL')
,('AAA',0,'Cola')
,('AAA',0,'Incentives')
```

Create a sortKey `row_number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0))` and order by that sort key in pivot like.

```
SELECT items, 
       [aaa] 
FROM   (SELECT branch, 
               payroll, 
               items, 
               Row_number() 
                 OVER ( 
                   ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) sortKey 
        FROM   #temp) ABC 
       PIVOT ( Max(payroll) 
             FOR branch IN ([AAA]) ) AS pvt2 
ORDER  BY sortkey 

DROP TABLE #temp
```

Output:

```
Items           AAA
BasicPay        0
Overtime        0
Paid Hol        0
Sunday OT       0
Thirteen MO     0
Gross Amount    0
WithTax         0
SSS Cont        0
SSS Loan        0
Pagibig Cont    0
Pagibig Loan    0
Medicare        0
Total Ded       0
Net with OD     0
Net no OD       0
CASH ADVANCE    0
MEAL            0
Cola            0
Incentives      0
```

Comment: it works out only with one record but what if I have many records?

Comment: if one is sorted, then others will automatically sorted. SortKey column reprent sort of whole table. If this is not please explain you situation